# How to execute a function on an element that has been selected by the value of a data-attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Sorry for the long winded question. My scenario is this.

I have 10 HTML consecutive elements, each listed as so:
(I have left the divs empty for the sake of clarity as they’re not relevant)

```
<div class="item" data-id="1" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translateX(0px) 
translateY(0px)">
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="card-add"> </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

All of the elements are identical apart from the ‘data-id’ attribute. Within each element the data-id ranges from 1-10.
What I am aiming to do is select the ‘item’ by its data-id value, and then execute a function on the ‘card-add’ div relative to the item selected.
The value to be selected will be randomly generated from specific numbers numbers.

My code so far:

```
// select the value

     myNumbers = [1, 2, 6, 9, 11];
     var item = myNumbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * myNumbers.length)];


 // use this to select the current item

     var itemTemp = ($("[data-id=" + item + "]"));


// attempting to execute a function on this.

      $(itemTemp).find(".card-add").each(function() { 
        *do stuff here*
      }
```

Obviously, this doesn’t seem to be working. I think it has something to do with binding the ‘find’ and ‘each’ function.

Does anyone have solutions around this?

Comment: Your array is declared as `myNumbers`, but your `item` attempts to get an index of `myItems`. Once you correct that, it works.

Comment: sorry this was a typo, its fixed and still not working

Comment: Now you are missing `)};` at the very bottom of the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Change the speech marks to quotations:

$(itemTemp).find('.card-add').each(function() {
*do something*
}